# Javascript form validation UNDEFINED

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the following javascript being included in some PHP which I am writing. The problem is that it is not working and developer tools keeps saying "'validate_entry' is undefined" but I don't know what I'm doing

My code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate_entry()
{
    var name=document.getElementById("submitted").value;
    var system=document.getElementById("system").value;
    var details=document.getElementById("description").value;
    if(name.trim() == "")
    {
        alert("The name you entered is too short");
        return false;
    }    
    if(name.length > 64)
    {
        alert("The name you entered is too long");
        return false;
    }
    if(system.trim() == ""
    {
        alert("System is not valid");
        return false;
    }
    if(details == "")
    {
        alert("Description cannot be empty");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

and I have the following form:

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST" onsubmit="return validate_entry();">
<table>
<tr>
<td><label for="submitted">Issue Submitted By</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="submitted" id="submitted" tabindex="<?php echo $header[0]++; ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<?php $systems = get_system_names($connection);
if($systems==FALSE)
{
    echo "<td></td>\n";
    echo "<td></td>\n";
}
else
{
    echo "<td><label for=\"system\">System Name</label></td>\n";
    echo "<td><select name=\"system\" id=\"system\" tabinex=\"". $header[0]++. "\">\n";
    echo "<option>Please Select</option>\n";
    foreach($systems as $system)
    {
        echo "<option value=\"{$system[0]}\">{$system[1]}</option>\n";
    }    
    echo "</select></td>\n";
}    
?>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="description">Issue Description</label></td>
<td><textarea name="description" id="description" tabindex="<?php echo $header[0]++; ?>"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" tabindex="<?php echo $header[0]++; ?>"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php echo "</form>\n";
```

Comment: Syntax error in your if statement. missing closing `)` on the line with `if(system.trim() == ""`. Fixing that might fix your broken code. Let me know if that fixes your problem.

Comment: Isn't DevTools also telling you about the syntax error?

Comment: `alert("The name you entered is too short");` that should read as `alert("You have a syntax error in this conditional statement.");` ;-)

Comment: @Mic1780 seems we've all fallen onto deaf ears. The OP can take it up with the low-quality answer given below.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure the positions of the JavaScript is after the html code
2. Try to test the JavaScript function using browser console
3. If it did work try to submit and handle other errors :)

Comment: not much of a solution here, and nothing that hasn't already been said in comments.